# How to keep a numeric sequence in a pandas DataFrame column that only increase?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'minutes':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
    'score1': [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2],
    'score2': [0,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2],
    'sum_score': [0,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,3,4]
})
```

Output:

```
   minutes  score1  score2  sum_score
0        1       0       0          0
1        2       0       1          1
2        3       1       1          2
3        4       1       1          2
4        5       0       1          1
5        6       0       2          2
6        7       0       1          1
7        8       1       1          2
8        9       1       2          3
9       10       2       2          4
```

The columns `score1` and `score2` are not sequentially increasing. There are rows in which its values decrease.

When loop through each row, I would like to remove all previous rows where values are higher than the current one considering columns `score1` and `score2`.

I tried to apply masks:

```
m1 = (df['score1'] > df['score1'].shift(-1))
m2 = (df['score2'] > df['score2'].shift(-1))
df = df.loc[~(m1 & m2)]
```

But it does not work as expected.

I expect to get this:

Output:

```
   minutes  score1  score2  sum_score
0        1       0       0          0
1        2       0       1          1
4        5       0       1          1
6        7       0       1          1
7        8       1       1          2
8        9       1       2          3
9       10       2       2          4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
x = df[["score1", "score2"]][::-1].cummin()[::-1]
mask = (df.score1 == x.score1) & (df.score2 == x.score2)

print(df[mask])
```

Prints:

```
   minutes  score1  score2  sum_score
0        1       0       0          0
1        2       0       1          1
4        5       0       1          1
6        7       0       1          1
7        8       1       1          2
8        9       1       2          3
9       10       2       2          4
```